# Elasticsearch - Backup and Restore on Found cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running my cluster on found (So no option to add plugins), and I am trying to configure s3 bucket to be able to create snapshots of my own.

I managed to configure the bucket but now I am trying to run the actual backup.

Is there a way to configure scheduled backup in elasticsearch? or I need to manually trigger a backup by sending a request to elasticsearch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How to use a custom repository is documented here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/found/current/custom-repository.html

Note that we do snapshots every 30 minutes already: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/found/current/restoring-snapshots.html

A more appropriate place for Found-related questions is this forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/c/found

Comment: Thanks Alex. I read those 2 documents, I managed to configure my own bucket. My problem is how to run the actuall back to this new bucket. I know that found already run a backup every 30 minutes, but I don't have access to those backups, if for example I want to restore this backup on my local cluster. This is why I configured my own bucket.